# Unicode problem Django-Python-URLLIB-MySQL

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, urllib

I am fetching a webpage (http://autoweek.com) and trying to process it but getting encoding error. Autoweek declares "iso-8859-1" encoding and has the word "Nürburgring" (u with umlaut)

I do:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
webpage = urllib.urlopen(feed.crawl_url).read()
webpage.decode("utf-8")
```

it gives me the following error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 7768-7773: unsupported Unicode code range"
```

if I bypass .decode step and do some parsing with lxml library, it raises an error when I am saving parsed title to database:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 45-50: unsupported Unicode code range
```

My database has character set utf8 and collation utf-general-ci

My settings:
 Django
 Python 2.4.3
 MySQL 5.0.22
 MySQL-python 1.2.1
 mod_python 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[autoweek.com](http://autoweek.com) seems confused about it's own encoding. It declares conflicting charset definitions:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and later...

```
<meta charset=iso-8859-1"/>.
```

iso-8859-1 is the correct one since this is returned in the header from the web server and by the `.info()` method (and it actually decodes), but this demonstrates that you can't necessarily rely on the Content-Type declaration in web pages. You should follow the method described by lavinio.

Answer (score 3):

If the `webpage` declares encoding `iso-8859-1`, can't you just do `webpage.decode("iso-8859-1")`?

At that point, `webpage` is decoded for your app. When it is written into the database, the mapping there should handle the char-to-utf8 encoding.

To get the correct encoding, either tell the webserver that you only accept, say, UTF-8 and then that's what you'll (hopefully) always get, since just about everyone reads UTF-8 (or you could try it with ISO-8859-1); or use .info to inspect the encoding name of the stream returned.

See [urllib2 - The Missing Manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml) and [Quick reference to HTTP headers](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/http.html) for details.

Comment: I need serialize this solution for all pages (of different encodings) I am fetching. So I have to fetch, extract encoding (if it's declared) and then decode.

Any easier solution?

Comment: No. It's the only solution, unless you want to throw away the incorrect characters. And it's honestly not very complicated.

Comment: +1 you need to decode using iso-8859-1. I've verified this against your URL and it works fine.